# How to get rid of GNOME Shell Integration extension in Chromium on Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome, chrome

I installed Debian 9.1 with KDE and Chromium. In Chromium there is a built-in extension called "GNOME Shell Integration" that I cannot remove or disable (it is "installed by system administrator", which is, in theory, me). However, I *do not* use GNOME, and package `chrome-gnome-shell` is *not* installed according to Aptitude. If I go to the extension's options, it says: *"Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected"*, which is correct.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo rm /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/chrome-gnome-shell.json
sudo rm /etc/chromium/policies/managed/chrome-gnome-shell.json
```

You may also need to delete the extension from the extensions folder in your profile path.

You can find this path @ chrome://version/ in the browser.

From: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIbtegrationForChrome/Installation#Troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you, worked. It's stupid this is forced even on those who don't use GNOME, rather than it being a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 but I managed to remove the extension using the following command:

```
sudo apt purge chrome-gnome-shell
```